# Suppressing print output in python3 with file parameter

Tags: python

I have several functions that I want to set the verbosity level of. Currently, I'm handling it like so:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, foo_stuff, verbose=True):
        self.print_file = None if verbose else open(os.devnull, 'w')

    def do_stuff(self):
        print('doing stuff', file=self.print_file)
```

This works, but I don't like that I never close the file `self.print_file.`

For cleanliness, I'd prefer not to wrap every single print function in a `with open(...)`. I was wondering if anyone could suggest another way of doing this. For this application, I don't think the python logging module will work.

Answer (score 1):

atexit module may help. write a cleanup function in your Foo class and register it by calling

```
atexit.register(function, args)
```

to be called before your program exits.

Comment: Researching your suggestion lead me to the magic method `__del__` (https://rszalski.github.io/magicmethods/). Do you know if this approach works? ...it comes with a warning on this type of operation

Comment: Never used it. Checked the page you linked, it looks promising, I would definitely give it a shot :) But be sure that you read the warnings first.